# How do I use the CSS display property on clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to JavaScript, and I've been trying to use a button to show a particular element. I need to be able to clear some content of the page and display new content on the click of a button. I cant change pages, and need to stay on the same page. I am trying to change the display property of the element I want to display.

This is what I have tried:

```
//CSS//

<style>
    p {
      display: visible;
    }
    div {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

```
//HTML//

<body>
    <p id="textElem">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <button onclick="displayDiv()">View Form</button>
    <div id="hiddenElem">
      <form></form>
    </div>
<body>
```

```
//JS//
<script>
    const textElement = document.getElementById('textElem');
    cont hiddenElement = document.getElementById('hiddenElem');
    function displayDiv() {
  
    }
</script>
```

I do not know what the syntax is to reference CSS properties in Java Script. What I want to do is to change the display property of the paragraph to hidden and the display property of the div to visible when the button is clicked.

Could someone please help me out with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although I've answered, it's inconceivable that you couldn't have found a plethora of resources about this with a simple search. The [first result](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp) that comes up for me if I search "show hide elements javascript" shows exactly what you need.

Comment: display: visible - does not exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meet the `style` object.

```
function displayDiv() {
    textElement.style.display = 'none';
    hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the javascript `style` property for this. Check the below code for your requirement:

```js
function displayDiv() {
  document.getElementById('firstElem').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('secondElem').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hide {display:none;}
```

```html
<div id="firstElem">First Page</div>
<div id="secondElem" class="hide">Second Page</div>
<button onclick="displayDiv()">Click Here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Style rule `display: visible` - does not exist. And you can style these in these ways.

1 - Use property **display**:

```
function displayDiv() {
    hiddenElement.style.display = 'block';
    textElement.style.display = 'none';
}
```

2 - Use property **setProperty()**:

```
function displayDiv() {
   hiddenElement.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
   textElement.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
}
```

3 - Use property **cssText**:

```
function displayDiv() {
   hiddenElement.style.cssText = 'display: block;'
   textElement.style.cssText = 'display: none;'
}
```

This property (**cssText**) will allow you to set the **list** of styles you need. Like that:

```
hiddenElement.style.cssText = 'display: none; color: green; background-color: white';
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can directly use it in an index.html file.**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .hidden{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="paragraph">HTML, CSS, and JS are awesome.</p>
    <button onclick="displayDiv()">View Form</button>
        
    <div id="divBox" class="hidden">
        <form>
           <label>Name:</label><input/>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>
    const paragraph = document.getElementById('paragraph');
    const divBox = document.getElementById('divBox');
    function displayDiv() {
        paragraph.classList.add('hidden');
        divBox.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
</script>
<body>
</html>
```